# Blender applies only Location part of keyframing

Tags: animation, keyframes

So I am making keyframes of an empty object, to which there are other objects parented, I am doing changes in Loc/Rot/Scale, but as soon as I press play it offsets Rotation and Scale. I am sure the previous versions had the Loc/Rot/Scale option to choose, but I don`t see it in 3.0. or maybe the problem is not in it. The help  is appreciated.

Comment: The option to keyframe loc/rot/scale is definitely present in 3.0 and I've just verified with a monkey parented to an empty that it works at least for simple cases.  Do you perhaps have a keying set enabled?

Comment: I`ve found  loc/rot/scale option, it just was in a little different place somehow. But it didn`t work, you mean automatic keying? it`s not enabled. Strange but thanks for verifying

Comment: Anyway I don`t know what`s that but i created a new parenting and now it works. Guess I had to start with it at first.